# file upload in wordpress admin plugin how to

Tags: plugins, admin

i am making a small imagemerger utility for my client below is where i am up to

```
/* Runs when plugin is activated */
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'ImageMerge_install'); 

/* Runs on plugin deactivation*/
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'ImageMerge_remove' );

function ImageMerge_install() {

    add_option("ImageMerge_data", 'Default', '', 'yes');

}

function ImageMerge_remove() {
/* Deletes the database field */
    delete_option('ImageMerge_data');
}


if ( is_admin() ){

/* Call the html code */
add_action('admin_menu', 'ImageMerge_admin_menu');

    function ImageMerge_admin_menu() {
            add_options_page('Image Merging Utility', 'Image Merger', 'administrator',
            'ImageMerger', 'ImageMerge_html_page');
        }

    function ImageMerge_html_page()
    {
            echo '<pre>'.print_r($_REQUEST);
        ?>

<div>


    <form name="Image" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
        <p>First Image = <input type="file" name="first" id="first" /></p>
        <p>Second Image =<input type="file" name="second" id="second" /> </p>
        <p><input type="submit" /></p>


    </form>
</div>

<?php
    }
}

?>
```

The above code displays the form correctly with two input fields now i want to grab the contents of these two files and apply image processing on them and then make them a single image for my client to embedd it later on in the post editor . 
For this what i am thinking of providing my client is to save the file in some folder and give instructions to the client to embedd the image he is creating from this utility to his posts.

Please guide me how can i grab the post data especially the $_FILES  i do not want to save any thing to database right now but in future may be yes.

Comment: This is a PHP question. Migrating to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I believe this is a *PHP* question and not a *WordPress* question, although I posted the solution anyway.

This is simply a matter of using the `$_FILES` rather than `$_REQUEST`.

If you change `echo '<pre>'.print_r($_REQUEST);` to this:

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($_FILES);
```

And then upload a file using your form, it will display the file that was just used in the form. I tested this and got this result after uploading the same image used in my Gravatar:

```
Array ( [first] => Array ( [name] => HoaH-Sonic-3Dredesign.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpFB13.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 69181 ) [second] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) )
```

Comment: Even though the question and answer aren't, strictly speaking, WordPress-specific, this is possibly an on-topic question, and useful, for two reasons: 1) by default, WordPress uses `$_POST` data, so knowing to use `$_FILES` data is helpful; and 2) by convention, WordPress settings forms generally aren't `multipart`. I know I have run into both issues in the past, when first working with file uploads in settings forms.